# Handle Sql Server Geography datatype with Simple.Data

Tags: sql-server, geography, simple.data

Its a pretty basic scenario. I have a table with a Geography datatype in a Sql Sever Database.  I can access basic crud functionality via Simple.Data with all my other tables except this one.

When I attempt to access the table (any method insert update etc...)  It throws a 'can not cast from dbnull to string'

Short of deleting my table column or hacking the Simple.Data src, has anyone found any work arounds?

Apologies, for lack of code, I'm posting from my phone but will edit shortly if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this as an issue on GitHub: http://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/issues/163

Comment: Thanks Mark, as I understand the issue, you're now simply 'ignoring' the column as opposed to throwing the DbNull error? Is there any chance of implementing `SqlGeography` ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I'll definitely add proper support for all UDTs.